# Expat XML Generator APIs

Tags: xml, expat-parser

Is Expat more popular as an xml parser or as an xml generator? Please let me know some basic 1-2 APIs if using Expat as an xml generator.

Answer (score 0):

Expat is an event based XML parser. You can specify code which gets called based on a specific parsing event. Expat does not generate anything. You have to generate XML in the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Expat is an XML reader/parser not a writer/generator. There is zero XML writing in Expat.

Note that when implementing your own XML writer special characters like `&` and `<` will need escaping.  That is the key thing to get right in an XML writer.